# Control Breake Logic Using Date

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I am having a hard time figuring out how to read multiple lines of a text file and produce the required output. I tried the datetime format but it is not going anywhere. I would greatly appreciate any help

What is being asked is:
Write Photo Report - For this part of the project we will take a data file and use Control Break logic on it to produce a report to the screen. The control break will be on the Year the file was created. The data file will have the following format (one field per line):

```
Date Created (in the form DD-MM-YYYY) Filename
Number of Bytes
```

For example, the following input file:

```
25-02-2019 
MyTurtle.GIF 
6000 
11-05-2019 
Smokey.GIF 
4000
```

I am not able read and output the date in the file. What I currently have is:

```
def openFile(self):

    myFile = self.inputFile.getText()
    fileName = open(myFile, "r")
    text = fileName.readline()

    x = "%4s%25s%25s\n\n" % ("File Name", "Date Created", "Number of Bytes")

    date_str_format = '%Y-%m-%d'
    jobs = []
    
    for i in fileName:
        d = datetime.strptime(i[0],'%m-%d-%Y')
        if d in i:
            date = i
            x += "%4d\n" % date
```

Comment: Please note that stack overflow is not an appropriate place to ask for help with homework. Please edit your question so it is clear what particular technical problem or issue you are asking help for. Eg what part of your code is not working the way you are expecting

Answer (score 0):

You can use the built-in module `re` to extract all the file names, dates and bytes from your file:

```
import re
from datetime import datetime

with open('file.txt', 'r') as f:
    t = f.read()

dates = re.findall('\d\d-\d\d-\d\d\d\d', t) # Find all the dates in the form of 00-00-0000
files = re.findall('\w+\.\w+', t) # Find all the file names in the form of text.text
byte = re.findall('(?<!-)\d\d\d\d', t) # Find all the number of bytes in the for of a four digit number without a dash behind it

print("File Name".ljust(15), "Date Created".ljust(15), "Number of Bytes".ljust(15))
for d, f, b in zip(dates, files, byte):
    print(f.ljust(15), d.ljust(15), b.ljust(15))
```

Output:

```
File Name       Date Created    Number of Bytes
MyTurtle.GIF    25-02-2019      6000           
Smokey.GIF      11-05-2019      4000
```

Answer (score -1):

For this, you need to read all the lines in the file then process 3 lines at a time to generate a data row for the report.

Try this code:

```
from datetime import datetime

ss = '''
25-02-2019 
MyTurtle.GIF 
6000 
11-05-2019 
Smokey.GIF 
4000
'''.strip()

with open ('myfile.txt','w') as f: f.write(ss)  # write data file

#############################

def openFile(self):

    fileName = open('myFile.txt', "r")

    x = "{:<20}{:<25}{:<25}".format("File Name", "Date Created", "Number of Bytes")
    print(x)  # header row 
    
    lines = fileName.readlines()  # all lines in file
    for i in range(0,len(lines),3):  # index every 3 lines
        dt = lines[i].strip()  # date
        filename = lines[i+1].strip()  # file name
        filesize = lines[i+2].strip()  # file size
        d = datetime.strptime(dt,'%d-%m-%Y')  # format date
        x = "{:<20}{:<25}{:<25}".format(filename, str(d), str(filesize))  # data row
        print(x)
        
openFile(None)
```

Output

```
File Name           Date Created             Number of Bytes
MyTurtle.GIF        2019-02-25 00:00:00      6000
Smokey.GIF          2019-05-11 00:00:00      4000
```